# Error when making unique XSD element

Tags: xml, xsd, unique, categories

Im making a small xsd/xml file for a restaurant based system.

Here is the code that i have for my XSD file:

```
<xs:element name="table_cat">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="category" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="category_id" type="CatID" />
              <xs:element name="catdescription" type="Length50"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:unique name="unique-catid">
      <xs:selector xpath="category" />
      <xs:field xpath="category_id"/>

    </xs:unique>

  </xs:element>
```

but whenever i have more than 1 Category_ID field in the XML file i keep getting the following error:

```
The field 'category_id' is expecting at the most one value.
```

Ive tried different solutions to make it work but nothing seems to work.

Hope you can help
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what constraint you are trying to express - it's difficult to reverse engineer your requirements from incorrect code.

It strikes me as a poor design anyway: you've got a repeated sequence of (id, description) pairs with no container element around the pair. That's going to make processing the data unnecessarily difficult.

Perhaps you want

```
<xs:unique name="unique-catid">
  <xs:selector xpath="category_id" />
  <xs:field xpath="."/>
</xs:unique>
```

But I can't really tell if that's your intent.